# Busy server indication during django forms POST

Tags: django-forms

How can I show a busy server icon to a user for Django form post and remove it with failure or success message when a response from the background process is receive ?  I cannot do the POST using javascript. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I had to use Javascript in the end.